# How to get all tags of all collections products with tag link

Tags: shopify, translation

I need to fetch all the tags on my collection page and display it within tag link.

I use this below code :

```
{% assign collection = collections.all %}
{% paginate collection.products by 1000 %} 
     <h3>All Tags</h3>
     <div id="tags">
      {% if collection.tags.size == 0 %}
        No tags found.{% else %}
       {% for tag in collection.tags %}
           <a href="{{ collection.url }}/{{ tag | handle }}">
            {{ tag }}
           </a>
          {% unless forloop.last %}, {% endunless %}
      {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </div>
{% endpaginate %}
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a built-in solution rather than `paginate`
use like it

```
<h3>All Tags</h3>
<div id="tags">
{% if collection.all_tags.size == 0 %}
   No tags found.
{% else %}
   {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
      {{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}
      {% unless forloop.last %}, {% endunless %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace below code :

```
<a href="{{ collection.url }}/{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</a>
```

To this :

```
{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}
```